# Digraph intermediate connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, reference-request

What's the name for a digraph such that for each pair of vertices $u,v$, there is either a path from $u$ to $v$ or a path from $v$ to $u$? I'd call it just connected, since this is an intermediate property between weak and strong connectivity, and is in fact equivalent to the existence of a path containing all vertices. However, I'm not an expert of the subject, and I was unable to find any reference about this, so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `connected' is fine. For example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29) and [Tutte](http://books.google.com/books?id=uTGhooU37h4C&lpg=PP1&dq=graph%2520theory&pg=PA132#v=onepage&q&f=false) agree. However, since "the number of systems of terminology presently used in graph theory is equal, to a close approximation, to the number of graph theorists," (R.P. Stanley, 1986) you might want to include the definition anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I had not seen the definition on Wikipedia. It was added by an anonymous user on last Oct 13, apparently. I had asked the same question in the talk page, but nobody answered me there.
The reference from Tutte is completely satisfactory for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another term that has been used is "unilateral" or "unilaterally connected".  I don't have a particularly strong opinion in favor of this terminology, but I am slightly opposed to just calling it "connected".  (I usually assume "connected" means "weakly connected" for digraphs.)  However, I must admit a reference by Tutte is good.

Some references for "unilateral":

- [Graph theory applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=IK7kreGl3vkC&lpg=PA94&ots=93sDbu8KmP&dq=unilateral&pg=PA94#v=onepage&q=unilateral&f=false) by L. R. Foulds
- [On minimal feedback vertex sets of a digraph](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=01083970) by Frank Harary (I think Harary's graph theory book uses it also)

Answer (score 1):

Such digraph is called *traceable*. For example, it is defined as such in the paper
http://www.ams.org/bull/1976-82-01/S0002-9904-1976-13955-9/S0002-9904-1976-13955-9.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems, however, that the definition of traceable graph in such paper requires the existence of a Hamiltonian path. This is not equivalent to what I am asking; I am not interested whether the path visits each vertex *exactly once*, as long as it does visit all of them. For example, the digraph $\{(a,b),(b,a),(a,c),(c,a),(a,d)\}$ is "connected" as I'm meaning, but it is not traceable as the shortest path visiting all vertices is $bacad$ (or $cabad$), thus visiting $a$ twice. The same graph is also not strongly connected, as no edge starts from $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Such a graph is called a semiconnected graph. You can find references to it in Cormen and Diestel's book on graph theory http://diestel-graph-theory.com/

Comment: Thanks… but again, it doesn't quite seem to be the same thing. In Diestel's book I could only find a definition for semiconnectedness of submultigraphs of infinite graphs. It is not obvious to me how would this apply to digraphs in general.